# Unable to use classes in the installed local jar with maven in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, pom.xml

I have followed the steps of installing local jar (Project A) in another maven project (Project B) but I'm still not able to use classes of the project A in IntelliJ while programming for Project B.

Steps I followed -

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<full path to jar of Project A> -DgroupId=<groupId> -DartifactId=<artifactId> -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

And then I added the dependency in Project B's pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

Running mvn package is successful, and mvn clean install as well.

I'm able to see my jar in External Libraries as well, And also in .m2/repository

But when I use the classes in project A while writing some program fro Project B, I'm getting "Cannot resolve symbol" in Intellij.

[Error in Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnDnX.png)

Comment: First you should do `mvn install` on the first project and not using install:install-file .... and can not resolve symbol is not enough ... Is the class contained in your created artifact...... ?...

Comment: Is IntelliJ configured to use the same Maven installation?

Comment: @khmarbaise I didn't get what you meant by class contained in your created artifact. How do i check? And also, The jar is already generated with mvn clean install not sure what mvn install would do

Comment: @jordiburgos Ummm, I created a new project via maven only both the times so yes, the configuration must be same.

Comment: Have you tried to run "Reload" from Maven tool window?